# How to create a dynamic WHERE clause for a query using an array list

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate

I have a List<String> of categories and for each category, I want to add them to my WHERE clause by combining with AND operator like: 
 `SELECT question_id FROM question WHERE category = categ1 AND category = categ2 AND category = ...`

Since the size of the categories list is changing, I cannot do something like this:

```
String sql = "SELECT question_id FROM question WHERE category = ? AND category = ?";
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, stringMapper, "categ1", "categ2");
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: Checkout mybatis.  (spring-mybatis starter, I think).  It will require a little work to switch to it, but it is surprisingly good.  alos, I believe it is an improvement on using jdbcTemplates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either check if JDBC Template from Spring handle that for you using a syntax which could be something like (from the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.ResultSetExtractor-java.lang.Object...-), I don't think it does)

```
SELECT question_id FROM question WHERE category in (?...)
```

Or write your own query with the problems that may arise:

```
List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<>(categories.size());
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilde("SELECT question_id FROM question WHERE 1=1");
if (!categories.isEmpty()) {
  if (categories.size() == 1) {
    sb.append(" and category = ?");
  } else {
    sb.append(" and category in ");
    sb.append(categories.stream()
                        .map(ignored -> "?")
                        .collect(joining(", ", "(", ")")));                      
    sb.append(")"); 
  }
  parameters.addAll(categories);
}
Object[] paramArray = parameters.toArray();
jdbcTemplate.query(sb.toString(), stringMapper, paramArray);
```

Notes:

1. some security/quality tool may report SQL issues because you are writing a dynamic SQL.
2. Oracle put a limit on 1000 elements per IN. You would have to partition categories per group of 1000 (or less).
3. I used a `stream()` in a more or less strange fashion in order to generate the "?". If you use [commons-lang3](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#repeat-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-int-), you can replace it by `"(" + StringUtils.repeat("?", ", ", categories.size()) + ")"` (the example in the javadoc was probably done with this kind of use).
4. if you only have category as single criteria, you may probably remove the `1=1` as well as the `and`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this may work for you:

```
// The SQL Query
String sql = "SELECT question_id FROM question";
    
// Create the WHERE clause based on the number of items in List...
StringBuilder whereClause = new StringBuilder(" WHERE ");
StringBuilder ps = new StringBuilder("");
for (int i = 0; i < categories.size(); i++) {
    if (!ps.toString().isEmpty()) {
        ps.append(" AND ");
    }
    ps.append("category = ?");
}
whereClause.append(ps.toString()).append(";");
    
//Append the WHERE clause string to the SQL query string
sql = sql + whereClause.toString();
//System.out.println(sql);
    
/* Convert the categories List to an Object[] Array so as to
   pass in as varArgs to the jdbcTemplate.query() method. */
Object[] psArgs = categories.toArray(new Object[categories.size()]);
jdbcTemplate.query(sql, stringMapper, psArgs);
```